# Не корректно работает description

Tags: seo

В поиске по запросу - site:домен.ком стоит мое описание, которое я указывал. А по любому другому ключевому запросу, у меня вместо указанного description, просто пара рандомных предложений текста. Как сделать description одинаковым для всех запросов в поиске?

Answer (score 0):

Гарантированно - никак. Текст в сниппете запросозависимый, т.е. в зависимости от запроса для одной и то же страницы google выбирает наиболее релевантные, на его взгляд, фразы. Если не подтягивается содержимое description, то может быть несколько вариантов:

1. Description нерелевантен запросу - нужно переписывать его с учетом семантики
2. У вас слишком много разноплановых запросов на одну страницу - нужно перебирать семантику и то, как у вас раскиданы запросы по страницам.